# How to download the picture which is located on the same place on each url from a url list text file?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have a code which I wrote with the help of this community.  (shoutout to @chitown88)
Now I want to implement the same method for scraping photos on the pages. one example is the following URL:

https://www.meisamatr.com/fa/product/%D8%A2%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B4%DB%8C/%D9%84%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%B2%D9%85-%D8%AC%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%A8%DB%8C-%D8%A2%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B4%DB%8C/%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%B3%D8%8C-%D8%A7%D9%BE%D9%84%DB%8C%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%B1-%D9%88-%D8%B3%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B1/4647-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D9%86%D8%B3-%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%B3-%D9%84%D8%A8-%D9%87%D9%84%D9%88-%D9%87%D9%BE%DB%8C%D9%86%D8%B3.html

I want to download the full-size picture which can be found if we inspect element on the picture:

```
<img src="https://www.meisamatr.com/upload/thumb1/product/1518428319.jpg" alt="اسنس برس لب هلو هپینس" title="اسنس برس لب هلو هپینس" class="thumb" data-large-img-url="https://www.meisamatr.com/upload/product/1518428319.jpg" id="magnifier-item-0">
```

the following URL is what we need:

```
data-large-img-url="https://www.meisamatr.com/upload/product/1518428319.jpg"
```

Let's suppose we have a file called links.txt which looks like this

```
https://www.meisamatr.com/fa/product/آرایشی/آرایش-صورت/کانسیلر/6494-اسنس-کانسیلر-کموفلاژ-با-پوشانندگی-کامل-10.html
https://www.meisamatr.com/fa/product/آرایشی/آرایش-صورت/کانسیلر/6493-اسنس-کانسیلر-کموفلاژ-با-پوشانندگی-کامل-05.html
https://www.meisamatr.com/fa/product/آرایشی/آرایش-صورت/کرم-پودر/6492-اسنس-هایلایتر-برنزه-کننده-مایع.html
https://www.meisamatr.com/fa/product/آرایشی/آرایش-صورت/پودر-صورت/6491-اسنس-پودر-فشرده-صورت-10.html
.
.
.
```

The following is what I came up with. But it shows "No connection adapters were found for" error.

What do you suggest? Thank you in advance for your time.

```
>>> import requests
>>> import urllib.request
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    with open('links.txt','r') as f:
    urls = f.read().split()


for url in urls:
    try:
        source = requests.get(url).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
        page = soup.find_all('div', class_='slick-slide slick-active')
        pic = page.find('img', class_='thumb')['data-large-img-url']
        print(pic)
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(pic, "local-filename.jpg")

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're not too far off. Again just need to adjust to get those specific tags.

`soup.find_all` will return a list of elements. You'll need to iterate through those to get what you want. However, in the links I've seen, what you are trying to get is in the first instance of that tag, so I simply changed from `.find_all()` to just `.find()`

I also removed the `break`. With the `break`, your loop will stop once it reaches an error from a link, even if it didn't get through all the links. Removeing the break with let it continue to the other links even if it comes across a link that doesn't pull the image/url.

You also may want to have the image file name you save as to be dynamic, otherwise it'll overwrite each time:

```
import requests
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


with open('links.txt','r', encoding="utf8") as f:
    urls = f.read().split()

num = 1
for url in urls:
    try:
        source = requests.get(url).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
        page = soup.find('div', class_='single_slideshow_big')
        pic = page.find('img')['data-large-img-url']
        print(pic)
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(pic, "local-filename_%02d.jpg" %(num))
        num += 1

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: Thank you again chitwon88. You are always a great help. But unfortunately when I run the same code you provided I get the "Invalid URL 'h': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://h?" error and when I change it to use my list then I get the same error as before: "No connection adapters were found for...". I'm trying to change different things but I had no luck so far

Comment: My links.txt file is located in the same folder as python IDLE

Comment: Thank you again, Jason. I have sent you an email. Thanks again